# Return reversed list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python2.7, I tried to return a reversed list directly using the below code but it didnt return anything.

Code 1:

```
def reverse3(nums):
    return nums.reverse()
```

The below code works and I am confused by the difference between Code 1 and Code 2. Please explain what's happening here.

Code 2:

```
def reverse3(nums):
    nums.reverse()
    return nums
```

Comment: `list.reverse` does not return, it just reverses items.  `return nums[::-1]`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first thing you are passing the `return type` of reverse function which is `None`. This is due to the fact `reverse()` acts on the list changes the list and returns `None`

```
a=[1,2,3]

print a.reverse()
None

a
[3, 2, 1]
```

Where as if you did as `falsetru` saying you are returning a list which is the reversed order of the list and it does not change the actual list

**i.e)**

```
a=[1,2,3]

a[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
print a
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

obviously, `nums.reverse()` does not return any value.. it just reverses the list..